# How to mock custom block in Magento ecomdev test case

Tags: unit-testing, magento, phpunit, ecomdev-phpunit

I'm trying to test my block method with magento ecomdev phpunit. I have block like this:

```
<block type="airhotels/property_view_amenities" name="airhotels.property.view.amenities" template="airhotels/property/view/amenities.phtml" />
```

I'm trying to get block:

```
$block = $this->getBlockMock('airhotels/property_view_amenities');
```

and after this line my all tests stop working.

Can someone explain me how to mock block in ecomdev and test methods of this mocked block?

Comment: This line *does* create a mocked block instance, so the error must be after this line. Please show more code.